# How to use a foreach loop o an array for searching?

Tags: php

I have my source code here:

```
$title = "news1";

$a = array();
foreach($page_news as $keys=>$news) // this comes from controller including news1.
{
    $x[] = $news->title;
    $x[] .= $news->url;
}

// I want to get the index of matches where $x[values = "news1"]
$key_title = array_search($title,$a);
```

Then my question is : if I get the index of `news->title`, how can I get the correspondent index of `$news->url`?

Comment: Why do you have `$a = array();` and then `$x[]=...` ? And what is  `$x[] .= $news->url;` with `.=` ? `.=` is for string concatenation no?

Comment: `$x[] .= ...` doesn't work as you think.

Answer (score 1):

As you always add the url after the title, you could simply add one to the index of your title to get the index of the url.

```
$title = "news1";

$a = array();
foreach($page_news as $keys=>$news) {
    $x[] = $news->title;
    $x[] = $news->url;
}
$key_title = array_search($title, $a);
$key_url = $key_title + 1;
```

A better way would be to use a multi dimensional array and use the title as the key - in this way, you don't need `array_search`

```
$a = array();
foreach($page_news as $keys=>$news) {
    $x[$news->title] = [
        'title' => $news->title,
        'url' => $news->url
    ];
}
$entry = $a[$title];
echo $entry['title'];
echo $entry['url'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some idea to achieve it :

**1/ Create an associative array for each title + url :**

```
$title = "news1";

$a = array();
foreach($page_news as $keys = >$news) 
{
    $a[] = array(
        'title' => $news->title,
        'url'   => $news->url
}
```

Then to find the key of `$title` :

```
foreach ($a as $key => $data) {
    if ($data['title'] == $title) {
        $key_title = $key;
    }
}
```

Then `echo $key_title` will give you the key.

If you want to avoid the `foreach` loop, I recommand you to do what Phillip suggest : add the title as key.

**2/ If you know the title you want to search before the first `foreach` loop (in your example you have the title before), maybe you can get it in this loop :**

```
 $title = "news1";

$a = array();

$key = 0;
foreach($page_news as $keys => $news)
{
    $a[$key] = $news->title;

    if ($news->title == $title) {
        $key_title = $key;
    }   
    $key++;

    $a[$key] = $news->url;
    $key++;
}
```

Then `echo $key_title` will give you the key and `echo $key_title + 1` will give the key of the associated url.

**3/ And third idea is to do what the anwser if Philipp suggest with :**

```
$key_title = array_search($title, $a);
$key_url = $key_title + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using PHP 7+, you can use [`array_column`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to convert the data into an indexed list of objects...

```
$indexed = array_column($page_news, null, "title");
echo "url=".$indexed[$title]->url;
```

BUT if you don't need this data for anything else, you would be better off doing a simple `foreach` and compare it against each item.  This saves converting and storing all of the data which isn't used later ...

```
$url = "";
foreach ( $page_news as $news ) {
    if ( $news->title = $title )    {
        $url = $news->url;
        break;
    }
}
echo "url=".$url.PHP_EOL;
```

(this works in most versions of PHP)

Comment: [`array_column()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) is available since PHP 5.5. The second code sample works since PHP 4.

Comment: @axiac, correct - but array_column doesn't work with objects till PHP 7.